# storing values in a sequential order in an array from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I have this below JSON reponse. The Order attribute in the JSON can come in random order like 3, 7, 8 ,9.

```
var respponseArr = '{"Test3_3":{"Name":"Test3","Notes":"This is third note","Order":"3"}, {"Test7_7":{"Name":"Test7","Notes":"This is seventh note","Order":"7"}';
```

I want to loop through this JSON response and store in a JSON object in ascending order like below

```
var tempArr = '{'Order' : '1','Name': 'Test1', 'Notes': 'This is first Notes'}, {'Order' : '3','Name': 'Test3', 'Notes': 'This is third Notes'}, {'Order' : '7','Name': 'Test7', 'Notes': 'This is seventh Note'}';
```

JS

```
var respponseArr1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respponseArr))

for(var tmp1 in respponseArr1) {
    var temp2 = respponseArr1[tmp1];
    for(var num in temp2) {
        var ndata = temp2[num];
        for(var l in ndata) {
            console.log(tmp1 + ' -> ' + num + ' -> ' + l + ' = ' + ndata[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert to a array and use sort function

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, they cancel each other out.

Comment: "I have this below JSON reponse" where do you get this json from? Because it is not valid; there are two `{` for each `}` in that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) here as the value is already string. Then you need to make an array with all the objects inside `respponseArr` and then use sort method.

You can do the following,

```js
respponseArr = '{"Test7_7":{"Name":"Test7","Notes":"This is seventh note","Order":"7"}, "Test3_3":{"Name":"Test3","Notes":"This is third note","Order":"3"}}';

respponseArr1 = JSON.parse(respponseArr) // use JSON.parse only do not use JSON.stringify.

Object.values(respponseArr1);

arr = Object.values(respponseArr1).map(item => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))).sort((a,b) => Number(a.Order) - Number(b.Order));

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing them as an object, try storing them in an array. E.g:

```
responseArr = {[{Order: 1},{Order:2},...,{Order: n}]}
```

This will allow you to use the array methods like Sort() which have time complexity of n(log n) and space complexity of n.

OR

You can study about the Map() in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

All key value pairs in a new Map() global object are indexed.